# Payments - Remove Option to Choose Amount of FBCredits

Tags: payment, facebook-credits

I'll try to be short as I can:

1. Player Clicks "Buy"
2. Dialogue Box appears where player chooses how many FBCredits he wants to buy (even though the item costs 10 FBC)

Is there a possibility to remove this dialogue box and just complete the payment with 10 FBC without asking how many FBC I want to buy?